# objective c convert html to attributedtext

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to convert `html` into `NSAttributedString` to put inside of a `UITextView`. The code is not working, I am getting the error:

edit: it turns out the database was storing its values as string giving me the previous string error.  new error: it crashes on the last line of code when I am adding the attributed string to the `uitextview`.

```
[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

This error seems to be telling me that the dictionary at index 0 is nil?

```
  NSString *htmlString = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"><title></title><meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer"><style type="text/css">p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 14.0px ".SF UI Text"; color: #ff0000; background-color: #ffffff}span.s1 {font-family: ".SFUIText-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt; text-decoration: line-through}</style></head><body><p class="p1"><span class="s1">Your Message Here!</span></p</body></html>"";

  NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

  NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

  tx.attributedText = attrString;
```

the value of attrString is as expected:

```
@"Your Message Here!\n"
```

when I look at it in the inspector or with textedit feature in xcode it shows up as attributed text.

just in case I will add the code that grabs the string.

```
- (NSString *)requestMessageReply{

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myUrlGoesHere"]];

  NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
  NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

  NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

  if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
    NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li", @"/messages/3dba5c7db8696a08160f33537b000cda", (long)[responseCode statusCode]);
     }
    NSString * responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

  NSString * message = (NSString *)JSON[@"message"];

    return  message;
}
```

Comment: put the @ at the beginning of your string ->  *htmlString = @"....

Comment: I just pasted in the value,  that wasn't the error. Sorry about that. Thanks for catching that though.

Comment: Which line is the error at? Are you escaping the quotation marks after `PUBLIC`?

Comment: It is actually a complete string, I just pasted that text so you guys can see the value. it is happening at the last line.  tx.attributedText = attrString; the value in the inspector in xcode actually shows red attributed text.